# Windows program that always runs

Tags: c#, windows

I have a requirement that a Windows Forms C# .NET 2.0 program running in user-space (not a service) must always be running. As I'm not infallible and make coding mistakes, I wanted to know of any extra safeguards I could use to ensure this requirement is met. The things I've been thinking of are TaskScheduler to check it every 5 minutes, A stub watcher or a secondary process. Are these good / bad ideas?

Thanks,
Richard

EDIT: The reason I didn't use a service (the obvious and sensible answer!) was the program runs in a kiosk type environment and has has a heavy GUI component. The service option didn't work well across Windows 2000 - W7.

EDIT: The second reason not to use a service was the app needs internet access and on some of our customer sites, proxies are set up to only allow specific users (not the local system account) so it would be tricky to ensure access if multiple users log onto the machine.

Comment: You seem to be saying how do i create something that works like a windows service but isn't a windows service.  Can you explain why you don't want a windows service so we can understand better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What's wrong with Windows Services? They're designed to do exactly what you want.

Comment: exactly, if you need some guI component for windows service, then create one and users can choose to open it  and adjust settings and stuff

Comment: Richard you can also have an app monitoring tool which verifies you app is up and running every some minutes, smth like Nagios for example.

Comment: @Ben the only reason it's not a service is it has a heavy gui (it's deployed in a kiosk type situation). The required platforms are Windows 2000 to W7 and how a GUI is rendered by a service has changed making it perform inconsistently.

Comment: @Davide - yes an app monitoring tool could work, I have no experience with them so feel free to recommend any that have worked for you in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three approaches that you can take:

1. Heartbeat Message.

   A heartbeat is useful in a distributed application and is simply message that is sent (from let say a client to server) to confirm that it is still healthy/running.
2. Manager Process

   A stub program, implemented as either a user process or a service. It launches the main application, monitors any unhandled exceptions, reports errors, and restarts on failure.
3. An exception guard on the entry point.

   A try-catch-all in the application entry point.

I would recommend either of the first two options; the third option, the try-catch-all, is a particular nasty hack for the lazy and inexperienced programmer (IMHO).

I have successfully used both heartbeat and manager process in a large distributed application.

**UPDATE**

As for ready-to-go™ restart managers, take a look at the Windows API Codepack as discussed in Emmanuel Istace blog post (http://istacee.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/automatic-recovery-restart-in-net-application/).

You can install the package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Core/

Comment: thanks very much for you answer - it's good to hear of some real world experience.

Comment: You are welcome Richard. I've just read your updated question and have more advice/experience to offer regarding Kiosks. I would definitely recommend the manager approach implemented as a user process as it will give you less difficulties when you need to deploy to the client site. Also (this is just a thought) you might want to schedule an fresh application launch each morning before opening hours (assuming it is for general public use) as that way you are guaranteed that it has not entered some known state from the previous day and that the application does not limp on.

Comment: @Petah. See updated answer. If you need more help, let me know. I'll be interested in hearing if this works for you; I've only quickly researched and would like to know if it is something useful.

Answer (score 5):

Task scheduler is a cheap solution for this which does work.  I use this to keep our Perforce Proxy server running (had some issues with the service), and so far there's been no problems - though now I've said that the server's probably exploded!

However, the most complete solution is a Windows service which invokes your app.  You can make that service catch error return codes from the app, restart it on failure and notify you by email, which may help you diagnose and fix those issues.  I think the Task Scheduler does something similar but it won't be able to provide as much insight into your application as a custom service.

If you're unsure of how to do that, then something like this should work: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/csharpsvclesson1.aspx

Comment: the service idea was one I considered but it becomes a little tricky with permissions. Service that run as local system account aren't by default able to start applications running as a user which is needed for proxy settings.

Comment: That's true, though you should be able to set up your service running as a user, so it should be able to start applications (even GUI applications) as that user.  I've seen this with our CC.NET service which runs as a build user.

Comment: Absolutely but the problem occurs when other users log on - to access the internet through the proxy the app needs to be running as the logged on user. If a service is configured to run as one user, this becomes tricky.

Comment: Ah so might the GUI be running under different user accounts?  Yes that does become trickier.  Task scheduler does better there, as you can add a logon script for each user that makes sure that the scheduled task is configured.  If Dennis' answer does the job though, then great.

Comment: that's right, it will be running under different accounts. The task scheduler is definitely something i'll try out though so thanks very much for your answer.